# plotly timeline using multiple x_start and x_end

Tags: python, plotly, timeline, gantt-chart, streamlit

I have a Gantt to plot. I'm using this code:

```
 fig_wbs_gantt_complessivo_pianificato=px.timeline(df.query(
                "Stream !=['Complessivo'] & Progetto==@proj1"
            ),
        x_start='Data Inizio Actual',
        x_end='Data Fine Actual',
        y='Fase',
        color="Stato",
        title=f"<b>GANTT di Dettaglio Actual {proj1}</b>",
        color_discrete_map={"Da Iniziare": "grey","In Ritardo": "#FFA07A",
        'Scaduta':"#F08080",
        'Inserire Actual':"#FFF8DC",
         'Completata':"#7FFFD4",
          'In corso':"LightBlue",
           'Completata in ritardo:':"#90EE90"},
```

and I have 4 dates.
`Data inizio pianificata` and `data fine pianificata` are the "planned date"
`data inizio actual` and `data fine actual` are my actual date.
I'd Like to display in the graph both actual and planned.

The columns I have are:
Fase - 'Data Inizio Actual'- 'Data Fine Actual' - 'Data Inizio Pianificata' - 'Data Fine Pianificata'